# using html as front end and text file as back end can save the data in android

Tags: android

My requirement is doing a project with android, now I developed the project in asp.net and call the URL in android web view. It works fine with the internet connection, but when internet is not available the problem occurs, what I have to do?

using html as front end and text file as back-end can save the data and sync when internet connection available, Is it possible?
or any other easy method to do?
please provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do what you said. You could have a local copy of the web inside the app assets folder and, for example, you can load it like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index.html");
```

Then you will have to implement an automatic downloader for the new online version. You could do it by putting a simple txt file with the current version (that you have to compare with the one in the app assets) or you could do a restapi that also handles the download (that's the better way, but it needs more time obviously).

Also, you have to write the files you download (for the new version) to the app internal memory (you could get the folder with "*context.getFilesDir()*") and then check if there is a version of the webapp inside that folder and if not fall back to the one in assets directory (that's included with the app apk).